# Dicas de segurança no upload de imagens com php

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de dicas para um upload seguro de imagens com php. Vários usuários terão acesso, quais dicas de segurança vocês dariam?

Na internet, encontrei as seguintes dicas:

> 1º - Validar tamanho do arquivo (bytes);
>
> 2º - Validar width;
>
> 3º - Validar height;
>
> 4º - Validar extensão;
>
> 5º - Validar Mime Type;
>
> 6º - Remover os pontos, anteriores a extensão (ou codificar o nome com
>   MD5);
>
> 7º - Validar o arquivo binário da imgem... ex: PNG = ‰PNG

Existe algo mais que eu possa fazer para manter o upload seguro?

Comment: faça uma busca no site por cada item desses que descreveu e encontrará respostas para todos.

Comment: @DanielOmine Eu não quero a resposta para os itens que descrevi... Eu gostaria de saber se existe algo mais que eu possa fazer para validar... A única que tenho dúvida é em relação a verificação do arquivo, pois não sei qual o padrão do PNG, Jpeg, jpg e Gif...  ATT

Comment: refaça a pergunta

Comment: Importante também, desligar o mime-magic do Apache pra evitar o problema relacionado ao ítem 7. O ítem 6 não deveria existir, pois o ideal é subir a imagem com um codigo sequencial apenas. O nome pode servir pra fins de referência só. Aliás, se não vai manter o nome original, tem serventia nenhuma o MD5.